# Webstorm баг с кодом после перезагрузки

Tags: webstorm

Отключили свет, и, соответственно, выключился компьютер
После этого в проекте ***webstorm***-a код одного из файлов превратился в нечто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень длинная строка такого типа

Это можно как-то исправить, вернув исходный код?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не используете систему версионного контрола (Git или что-то другое), можно только надеяться, что [Local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/local-history.html#restore-changes-from-local-history) пережила перезагрузку компьютера.